# How to Get email id using asp.net mvc4 openid api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

Looking to get the email id along with the openid while
Using the Internet template for MVC4

This is available for auth using google but not for facebook

wondering how to get/request the email id in the extraData dictionary

Looking at the code in AspNetWebStack project at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/, it looks like

```
 OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient()
```

makes use of FacebookClient in DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll hosted at https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid

and the code in FacebookClient.GetUserData() has

```
                    var userData = new NameValueCollection();
            userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("id", graphData.Id);
            userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("username", graphData.Email);
            userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("name", graphData.Name);
            userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("link", graphData.Link == null ? null : graphData.Link.AbsoluteUri);
            userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("gender", graphData.Gender);
            userData.AddItemIfNotEmpty("birthday", graphData.Birthday);
            return userData;
```

which should return the email-id in username but it's not being returned

any help is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The provided Facebook OAuth client will not let you get anything beyond the default info. To get anything else, you need to be able to change the value of the `scope` parameter, something the included client doesn't allow. So, to get around this and still use the other boilerplate code the Internet template provides, you need to implement a custom OAuth client that follows the same pattern.

Since the entire ASP.NET source is open source, as is the OAuth library DotNetOpenAuth, you can actually look into the OAuth library and see exactly how the Facebook provider is built. Using that, I was able to come up with this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients;
using Validation;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace OAuthProviders
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The facebook client.
    /// </summary>
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA1704:IdentifiersShouldBeSpelledCorrectly", MessageId = "Facebook", Justification = "Brand name")]
    public sealed class FacebookScopedClient : OAuth2Client
    {
        #region Constants and Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// The authorization endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        private const string AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";

        /// <summary>
        /// The token endpoint.
        /// </summary>
        private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";

        /// <summary>
        /// The _app id.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string appId;

        /// <summary>
        /// The _app secret.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string appSecret;

        private readonly string scope;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="FacebookScopedClient"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="appId">
        /// The app id.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="appSecret">
        /// The app secret.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="scope">
        /// The scope (requested Facebook permissions).
        /// </param>
        public FacebookScopedClient(string appId, string appSecret, string scope)
            : base("facebook")
        {
            Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(appId, "appId");
            Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(appSecret, "appSecret");
            Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(scope, "scope");

            this.appId = appId;
            this.appSecret = appSecret;
            this.scope = scope;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// The get service login url.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="returnUrl">
        /// The return url.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>An absolute URI.</returns>
        protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
        {
            // Note: Facebook doesn't like us to url-encode the redirect_uri value
            var builder = new UriBuilder(AuthorizationEndpoint);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("client_id", this.appId);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("redirect_uri", returnUrl.AbsoluteUri);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("scope", this.scope);

            return builder.Uri;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The get user data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accessToken">
        /// The access token.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>A dictionary of profile data.</returns>
        protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
        {
            FacebookGraphData graphData;
            var request =
            WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + UriDataStringRFC3986(accessToken));
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    graphData = OAuthJsonHelper.Deserialize<FacebookGraphData>(responseStream);
                }
            }

            // this dictionary must contains
            var userData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graphData.Id)) { userData.Add("id", graphData.Id); }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graphData.Email)) { userData.Add("username", graphData.Email); }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graphData.Name)) { userData.Add("name", graphData.Name); }

            if (graphData.Link != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(graphData.Link.AbsoluteUri)) { userData.Add("link", graphData.Link == null ? null : graphData.Link.AbsoluteUri); }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graphData.Gender)) { userData.Add("gender", graphData.Gender); }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(graphData.Birthday)) { userData.Add("birthday", graphData.Birthday); }

            return userData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtains an access token given an authorization code and callback URL.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="returnUrl">
        /// The return url.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="authorizationCode">
        /// The authorization code.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The access token.
        /// </returns>
        protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            // Note: Facebook doesn't like us to url-encode the redirect_uri value
            var builder = new UriBuilder(TokenEndpoint);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("client_id", this.appId);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("redirect_uri", NormalizeHexEncoding(returnUrl.AbsoluteUri));
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("client_secret", this.appSecret);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("code", authorizationCode);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("scope", this.scope);

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string data = client.DownloadString(builder.Uri);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var parsedQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data);
                return parsedQueryString["access_token"];
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts any % encoded values in the URL to uppercase.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The URL string to normalize</param>
        /// <returns>The normalized url</returns>
        /// <example>NormalizeHexEncoding("Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fManage.aspx") returns "Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FManage.aspx"</example>
        /// <remarks>
        /// There is an issue in Facebook whereby it will rejects the redirect_uri value if
        /// the url contains lowercase % encoded values.
        /// </remarks>
        private static string NormalizeHexEncoding(string url)
        {
            var chars = url.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (chars[i] == '%')
                {
                    chars[i + 1] = char.ToUpperInvariant(chars[i + 1]);
                    chars[i + 2] = char.ToUpperInvariant(chars[i + 2]);
                    i += 2;
                }
            }
            return new string(chars);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The set of characters that are unreserved in RFC 2396 but are NOT unreserved in RFC 3986.
        /// </summary>
        private static readonly string[] UriRfc3986CharsToEscape = new[] { "!", "*", "'", "(", ")" };

        internal static string UriDataStringRFC3986(string value)
        {
            // Start with RFC 2396 escaping by calling the .NET method to do the work.
            // This MAY sometimes exhibit RFC 3986 behavior (according to the documentation).
            // If it does, the escaping we do that follows it will be a no-op since the
            // characters we search for to replace can't possibly exist in the string.
            var escaped = new StringBuilder(Uri.EscapeDataString(value));

            // Upgrade the escaping to RFC 3986, if necessary.
            for (int i = 0; i < UriRfc3986CharsToEscape.Length; i++)
            {
                escaped.Replace(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i], Uri.HexEscape(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i][0]));
            }

            // Return the fully-RFC3986-escaped string.
            return escaped.ToString();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

There are a few dependent libraries required to make this work as-is, all of which are available on NuGet. You already have DotNetOpenAuth; http://nuget.org/packages/Validation/ is another. The `OAuthJsonHelper` is a copy of an internal class used by DotNetOpenAuth - to get this provider to work I had to re-implement it in my own namespace:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Validation;

namespace OAuthProviders
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The JSON helper.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class OAuthJsonHelper
    {
        #region Public Methods and Operators

        /// <summary>
        /// The deserialize.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">
        /// The stream.
        /// </param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the value to deserialize.</typeparam>
        /// <returns>
        /// The deserialized value.
        /// </returns>
        public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream stream) where T : class
        {
            Requires.NotNull(stream, "stream");

            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is all provided **as-is**, with no guarantee that it will work via copy/paste - it's up to you to figure out how to integrate it into your project.

Comment: Thanks I've been poring over the code but not quite sure how to tie it together, it looks like there's a "scope" in the built-in facebookclient.cs which is set to email whereas your constructor has a scope parameter, should i assume it should be setup to string "email" ? thanks again

Comment: @Kumar The `scope` value needs to be one or more of the predefined "permissions" listed in the API. `email` is a default, but you will only see the info that the user has chosen to make public. The rest of the permissions can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: @Kumar It occurs to me that you don't really need a custom client to get email info, as it's part of the default info. As I mentioned just a moment ago, what you can access is determined by the user's profile settings. This provider lets you request permission to do things like post to a user's timeline (assuming they authorize your app).

Comment: the email id is not being returned by default, is there anything else that could be done to return this ?

Comment: @Kumar Facebook's API says that you only get email info with the `email` permission. Have you configured your application to request that permission, as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/#authorization ?